# Drag & Drop .Net

Tags: .net, forms, symlink, drag, drop

Typically we can drop an icon (.lnk) into a WinForms to get it's "Target" in fact it's a pretty easy task. However what has changed with Windows 10 and how can I do the same with a Windows 10 Start Menu Icon (is it a symlink? Or is there a way I can get its target path after dropping it into the form. When you drag any other Icon you get a + symbol (it is allowed) and then retrieve the path, If it is an Icon from the start menu you get a Circle with a line through it (can't drop it). So I am not sure why. Does anyone have any ideas?

Is there a reason why I can't Drag & Drop a windows 10 "icon" into my form? If so, can that be fixed? And finally. Beyond that how can I get it's "Target path" if it's not a .lnk when I drop it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why it isn't working for you.

The issue is typically when we used to do this we would set the "Effect" to Copy. Most do. In this case you need to set the effect to .link

```
e.Effect = (If(e.Data.GetFormats().Any(Function(f) f = DataFormats.FileDrop), DragDropEffects.Link, DragDropEffects.All))
```

it will then allow you to "Link" the file which will give you the .lnk for the start menu item (with the exception of UWP , Which I want to figure out now)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your source code fully looks like but using .Link instead of the regular .Copy on your .DragEnter Event will allow you to drag start menu icons onto the form

I have a simple winform with a label that allows drops in this project

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub DropHere_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles lblDropHere.DragDrop
    Dim file() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFullPath(file(0)))
End Sub
    Private Sub DropHere_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles lblDropHere.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I modified this from a drag and drop I use repeatedly in an application